# setTorchModeOnWithLevel not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, beta

I am using this method to turn the torch on:

```
- (void)checkTorch {
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devices]) {

        if ([device position] != AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            NSLog(@"This is the front camera");
            continue; // go to next device
        }

        NSLog(@"This is the back camera");

        if([device hasTorch] == NO){
            NSLog(@"this camera has no torch...");
            continue; // go to next device
        }

        NSLog(@"The camera has a torch");

        if([device isTorchAvailable] == NO){
            NSLog(@"The torch is not available...");
            continue; // go to next device
        }

        NSLog(@"The torch is available");

        NSError *outError;
        NSError *lockError;

        [device lockForConfiguration:&lockError];
        BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.2 error:&outError];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];

        if (lockError)
            NSLog(@"Error locking: %@", lockError.localizedDescription);

        NSLog(@"Torch Level: %0.0f", device.torchLevel);

        if(!success){
            NSLog(@"Could not activate torch: %@", [outError localizedDescription]);
            continue; // go to next device
        }

        NSLog(@"The torch is now active!");
    }
}
```

Which gives me this output (which is correct):

```
2014-06-10 08:52:30.677 [291:17894] This is the back camera

2014-06-10 08:52:30.679 [291:17894] The camera has a torch

2014-06-10 08:52:30.679 [291:17894] The torch is available

2014-06-10 08:52:30.682 [291:17894] Torch Level: 0

2014-06-10 08:52:30.683 [291:17894] The torch is now active!

2014-06-10 08:52:30.683 [291:17894] This is the front camera

2014-06-10 08:52:30.684 [291:17894] This is the front camera
```

However the torch never comes on.

-- I am running beta code however the latest API diffs show no change to this method or related methods so I'm not sure why it would not be working. I've asked on apple dev forums with no help.

Comment: Why is your code being called twice "This is the front camera" after the torch has been activated? Also why not try using [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

Comment: This code works for me on non-beta iOS/Xcode. @SamBudda mine also outputs "This is the front camera" twice.

Comment: @SamBudda `[device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];` does not work. It is outputting "This is the front camera" twice because it enters the block when `!= AVCaptureDevicePositionBack`, which there is 3 devices returned from `[device position]`. I'm getting `AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified`, `AVCaptureDevicePositionBack`, and `AVCaptureDevicePositionFront`.

Comment: @Stonz2 i'm glad it's working on non-beta iOS, not sure what in beta is causing it not to work. Although, turning on the flash from pull up menu causes crash randomly so maybe there is something going on behind the scenes with torch.

Comment: The reason that it says "This is the front camera" twice is because it assumes that the microphone is a front camera. `[AVCaptureDevice devices]` will give 3 objects- front camera, back camera, and iPhone microphone. If you just want cameras, you need to specify the media type with `devicesWithMediaType:`

Comment: I can confirm it is not working on iOS 8 beta 2. Looks like all existing flashlight apps do not work on iOS 8 beta 2.

Comment: does not work on 5s running 8.1.1 either. I've filed 19083935 with apple

Comment: Has anyone managed to turn the flash / torch off in ios8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently, successfully, using the following code to control the torch on iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus:

```
- (void)setTorchToLevel:(float)torchLevel
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (torchLevel <= 0.0) {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        }
        else {
            if (torchLevel >= 1.0)
                torchLevel = AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel;
            BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:torchLevel   error:nil];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```